# Módulo de floats em PHP retorna inteiros?

Tags: php, matemática, float, divisão

Como faço para obter o resto da divisão (operação módulo `%`) com casas decimais quando uso um divisor ou dividendo `float`?

**Exemplo:**

```php
echo 5 % 3; // imprime 2 como é esperado
echo 5.6 % 3; // imprime 2 quando deveria imprimir 2.6
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Existe a possibilidade de usar a função [`fmod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) <sup>(em inglês)</sup> que é apropriada para isso. Não sei se vai dar o resultado que você espera, mas no meu teste rápido foi ok.

Então você faria:

```
echo fmod( 5.6, 3.0 );
```

Isto vai imprimir `2.6`.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pwk9Ij) e [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/cpxbnizv-maniero). E [coloquei no **Github** para futura referência](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Fmod.php).

Answer (score 9):

O operador Módulo, server apenas para inteiros, para tal uso, você pode usar a função **[fmod](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fmod.php)** do PHP:

```php
fmod(5.6, 3); // imprime 2.6
```

Se usar apenas o operador Módulo (%), o valor obtido será o Maior Inteiro Menor que o resultado.

Answer (score 6):

Este operador funciona apenas com inteiros

Tem um comentário nesse [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.arithmetic.php) lembando isto.

> Note que o operador % (modulo) funciona apenas com inteiros (entre -214748348 e 2147483647)...

Experimente usar [`fmod()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fmod.php)