# Calcular mod em php

Tags: php

Como posso calcular **15,625 mod 23** apenas em PHP?

Procurei no google e em outros resources e nao obtive exito em minha busca, poderiam me passar mais informaçoes?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/704/101

Comment: Você precisa do resultado do mod como inteiro ou como float?

Comment: Obrigado @bigown

Answer (score 4):

Você deve fazer assim:

```
echo 15.625 % 23;
```

[Fonte](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)